# Symfony/Doctrine detects change in "money" field, even when no change has occurred?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a collection of "Entity A" records on my form. One of the properties of "Entity A" is as follows:

```
/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="amount", type="decimal", precision=65, scale=2, nullable=true)
 */
private $amount;
```

When I submit the containing form, Doctrine fires a preUpdate event for each "Entity A" object in the collection *even if absolutely nothing has changed*. The changeset looks like:

```
array:1 [▼
  "amount" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "5.00"
    1 => 5.0
  ]
]
```

Obviously a type-casting issue, but how can I prevent this? Do I really have to check each property in the changeset and verify that it actually changed?

I also tried the "number" form type with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem with preUpdate. It suppose to work this way.
If you have a look to the code the `preUpdate` is called in any case before the changeset is evaluated.

UnitOfWork.php lines 1063 - 1070

```
private function executeUpdates($class) 
{
    // .........
            if ($preUpdateInvoke != ListenersInvoker::INVOKE_NONE) {
            $this->listenersInvoker->invoke($class, Events::preUpdate, $entity, new PreUpdateEventArgs($entity, $this->em, $this->entityChangeSets[$oid]), $preUpdateInvoke);
            $this->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($class, $entity);
        }
        if ( ! empty($this->entityChangeSets[$oid])) {
            $persister->update($entity);
        }
    //.........
}
```

Meanwhile the problem with incorrect changeset still exists. I don't see any other way of fixing it rather than filter the values in the form before it gets to the entity. And that is another question...

Here is the code ho UOW determines change in the entity. It is `!==`

```
        if ($orgValue !== $actualValue) {
            $changeSet[$propName] = array($orgValue, $actualValue);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is helpful. You are right about the preUpdate, the real problem is the changeset being essentially incorrect.

It seems to me the fix would need to be somewhere in Symfony's form processing code? Values in money or number fields should be cast to the appropriate type before being passed to Doctrine.